# Android animation repeat

Tags: android, animation, repeat

I have problem with animation in Android. Between End and Start of this animation blink on screen whole image with no alpha effect. Animation begin with alpha 0 and ends too with alpha 0. I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

<scale
    android:duration="12000"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="2"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>

<alpha
    android:startOffset="10000"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0" />
</set>
```

and this code in java

```
imageView.startAnimation(animace);

animace.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView.startAnimation(animace);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
```

Comment: your title was saying something about **run()** but it is not mentioned in the code snippet you provided,please post the full code

Comment: Are you try `imageView.setAlpha(0f);` in `onAnimationStart` before calling  `imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`?

Comment: No, this not work, when setting alpha to imageview, then imageview stay transparent and animation show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the animations in the XML file are runned at the same time. You have both an animation that changes Alpha from 0 to 1 and one that changes from 1 to 0. I assume you want to run them in a sequence, so you should split them in separate files. One solution could be like so: (not tested)

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:startOffset="10000"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

scale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="12000"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="2"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

And then, in your code, start fade_in and scale at the same time, and run fade_out after fade_in has completed:

```
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
imageView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);

fadeInAmination.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        imageView.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
});
```

I am not sure where do you need to set Visible and Invisible, but you can attach an AnimationListener for each object and put them according to your needs.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I have in second alpha start ofset 10000, this animation is ok. And now i found solution thanks to @Stanislav. I dont know why, but setting visibility to INVISIBLE or VISIBLE not work (Android Studio do not show any error), but when i change this to setting alpha 0f at animationEnd and 1f at animatioStart, now is it working.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that one. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
    animace.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            imageView.setAlpha(1f);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            imageView.setAlpha(0f);
            imageView.startAnimation(animace);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```